# Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to create a model that receive one image and compute the image by two Softmax(two output). The code is:

```
base_model = InceptionV3(include_top=False)
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

#  first softmax
x_1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions_1 = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x_1)

#  second Softmax
x_2 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions_2 = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x_2)
my_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=[predictions_1,predictions_2])

#  train
my_model.compile(...)
my_model.fit_generator(...)
```

When training, I got error:

> ValueError: Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following
>   list of 1 arrays: [array([[0., 0., 0., 1.], [0., 0., 0., 1.], [0., 0.,
>   0., 1.], [0., 1., 0., 0.], [1., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0., 0.],...

Comment: Can you share how you have created your data generator? I'm assuming you have a two arrays with target values.

Comment: i just use image.ImageDataGenerator and train_datagen.flow_from_directory to  created my data generator.

Comment: `train_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(...)` </br> `train_data = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(...)`

Comment: I want to train two classifiers with  a set of data , although the two classifiers may be the same